# Why is my array of struct not resizing with Array.Resize?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, resize, streamwriter

I have an array of struct's declared as

```
public struct classMates
    {
        public string first;
        public string last;
        public string ID;
    }
```

I am using StreamReader  to read in a `.txt` file and my variables correspond to their relevant value. ie. first == first name, ID == phone number.

My array of struct is delcared as:

```
classMates[] classMateInfo = new classMates[43];
```

I have a method that is supposed to add a new member to my `.txt` file and append it to the end of my declared array. However, in order to do this, I will need to resize my array + 1 in order for a new member. Otherwise, it just overwrites an existing member.

I have my `Array.Resize` just after I call my method to add new members. However, once I've finished with that method, StreamWriting incurs and it saves it to variables ready to be written to the file.

```
static void addClassMates(classMates[] classMateInfo)
    {
        //I DECLARE MY ARRAY RESIZE HERE
        Array.Resize(ref classMateInfo, classMateInfo.Length + 1);
        //I am essentially creating a new space in my array for a new member, below.
        Console.Write("Enter first name: ");
        classMateInfo[classMateInfo.Length - 1].first = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter last name: ");
        classMateInfo[classMateInfo.Length - 1].last = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter phone number: ");
        classMateInfo[classMateInfo.Length - 1].ID = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to save the changes back to the file? [Y/N]");
        string temp = Console.ReadLine();
        if ((temp == "Y") || (temp == "y"))
        {                
            editNumber(classMateInfo);//A method where it saves it to variables ready to be StreamWritten.
        }
    }
```

After that, it then moves onto a method to add it into the file. However, with slight debugging I've found there is no new added space in my array for this value I'm trying to enter. I have [42] array placeholders, and with the help of Array.Resize, this should be in actual, [43].

My question is, why is my array not being resized as I ask it to? It seems I have misplaced it, and I really have no clear as to where I should put it.

Comment: Check the array size in the method `addClassMates` , looks like you are comparing the array size after the call to your method. You can't modify the array's reference in your method.

Comment: `struct` doesn't mean what you think it means. Why aren't you using a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your method in the following way:

`static void addClassMates(ref classMates[] classMateInfo)`

Notice the `ref` for the parameter.